# keep-alive configurations of spring-boot app

Tags: spring-boot, keep-alive, embedded-tomcat

I am trying to fix/debug an issue of too many closing connection in a spring-boot web app that uses embedded tomcat. The problem arise because it closes connection that should be kept alive.

Now, I found that tomcat has configuration that limit the number of keep-alive connection (see `maxKeepAliveRequests` in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html) and there are maybe other config that could be related to the issue. But my problem is that I don't see where are those parameters given, or how I could change them if default are used.

My question: where can I found a documentation that explain how to config spring-boot/embedded-tomcat keep-alive parameters, and which are those parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all tomcat properties can be configured via the properties file. The `keep-alive` related properties are one of those properties and that means they can only be configured programmatically. This is done by configuring a `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` bean. You can use the protocol handler to set the `KeepAlive` settings. An example below:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> tomcatCustomizer() {
    return (tomcat) -> tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers((connector) -> {
        if (connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol) {
            AbstractHttp11Protocol<?> protocolHandler = (AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector
                    .getProtocolHandler();
            protocolHandler.setKeepAliveTimeout(80000);
            protocolHandler.setMaxKeepAliveRequests(500);
            protocolHandler.setUseKeepAliveResponseHeader(true);
        }
    });
}
```

To know more about these settings please read the [tomcat 9 configuration reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html)

Comment: I don't have this problem anymore and I can't test it, but this looks to be a good solution. So I'll select it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.tomcat.max-keep-alive-requests) in the documentation shared by Dina Bogdan, and I was told that those properties vary depending on spring boot release version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also, your answer should be self contains, links are just to provide additional details or reference link

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Boot properties for controlling Tomcat keep-alive are:

```
server.tomcat.max-keep-alive-requests=100
```

Number of keep-alive sessions, default is 100

```
server.tomcat.keep-alive-timeout=60000
```

Number of msec of inactivity to keep each session alive

Answer (score -2):

These are the configuration-properties for tomcat server:

```
server.tomcat.accept-count=100 # Maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing threads are in use.
server.tomcat.accesslog.buffered=true # Whether to buffer output such that it is flushed only periodically.
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=logs # Directory in which log files are created. Can be absolute or relative to the Tomcat base dir.
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=false # Enable access log.
server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=.yyyy-MM-dd # Date format to place in the log file name.
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=common # Format pattern for access logs.
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=access_log # Log file name prefix.
server.tomcat.accesslog.rename-on-rotate=false # Whether to defer inclusion of the date stamp in the file name until rotate time.
server.tomcat.accesslog.request-attributes-enabled=false # Set request attributes for the IP address, Hostname, protocol, and port used for the request.
server.tomcat.accesslog.rotate=true # Whether to enable access log rotation.
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log # Log file name suffix.
server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns= # Comma-separated list of additional patterns that match jars to ignore for TLD scanning.
server.tomcat.background-processor-delay=10s # Delay between the invocation of backgroundProcess methods. If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.
server.tomcat.basedir= # Tomcat base directory. If not specified, a temporary directory is used.
server.tomcat.internal-proxies=10\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        192\\.168\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        169\\.254\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        127\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        172\\.1[6-9]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        172\\.2[0-9]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        172\\.3[0-1]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\
        0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1\\
        ::1 # Regular expression that matches proxies that are to be trusted.
server.tomcat.max-connections=10000 # Maximum number of connections that the server accepts and processes at any given time.
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=2MB # Maximum size of the HTTP post content.
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=2MB # Maximum amount of request body to swallow.
server.tomcat.max-threads=200 # Maximum amount of worker threads.
server.tomcat.min-spare-threads=10 # Minimum amount of worker threads.
server.tomcat.port-header=X-Forwarded-Port # Name of the HTTP header used to override the original port value.
server.tomcat.protocol-header= # Header that holds the incoming protocol, usually named "X-Forwarded-Proto".
server.tomcat.protocol-header-https-value=https # Value of the protocol header indicating whether the incoming request uses SSL.
server.tomcat.redirect-context-root=true # Whether requests to the context root should be redirected by appending a / to the path.
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header= # Name of the HTTP header from which the remote IP is extracted. For instance, `X-FORWARDED-FOR`.
server.tomcat.resource.allow-caching=true # Whether static resource caching is permitted for this web application.
server.tomcat.resource.cache-ttl= # Time-to-live of the static resource cache.
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8 # Character encoding to use to decode the URI.
server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects= # Whether HTTP 1.1 and later location headers generated by a call to sendRedirect will use relative or absolute redirects.
```

For more details check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Comment: So there is nothing about keep-alive?

Comment: It seems to be nothing about keep alive related, but you can dig more into that documentation, maybe you will find something useful or think how you can use those properties in a way that can solve your problems.

Comment: Would you know what source code read those param and pass them to tomcat? So I can directly go and see by myself

Comment: this answer doesn't answer about keep alive as asked in question, it is just a dump of all the properties.

Comment: I agree, these properties only confusing us more.